# Why does this regular expression find nothing? x00-xFF

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I was reading through this program update to see what is new and suddenly I see this thing:

```
 if( preg_match("/[\xE0-\xFF][\x80-\xFF][\x80-\xFF]/", $variablino_namerino) )
 {
    //do stuff
 }
```

I immediately googled preg_match and discovered this wonderful branch of programming techniques working wonders with regular expressions I have never even heard about. Watched a couple of videos and read a couple of documents. Then I started working this through and understood that it might be possible that  values present between E0 and FF might not be there, so I changed this expression so it should always find something:

```
if( preg_match("/[\x00-\xFF][\x00-\xFF][\x00-\xFF]/", $variablino_namerino) )
{
    //do stuff
}
```

and actually it does not! [So i thought this was the problem](http://www.marco.org/2008/06/04/tip-xml-doesnt-like-control-characters-x00-x1f), but it starts working after i change the statement to:

```
 if( preg_match("/[\x01-\xFF][\x01-\xFF][\x01-\xFF]/", $variablino_namerino) )
 {
    //do stuff
 }
```

where x01 is still a control character, right? Plus, the website is in UTF-8.

**So is it like you cannot include x00 in range because it is the NULL value or is it something different?**

Comment: NUL is end of string marker for ASCII-compatible encoding, so the pattern string ends at the first `\x00`. http://ideone.com/tjjlFC If you want to specify it, you should specify it with regex escape and not string escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to either double the backslashes or use single quotes when declaring the regex:

```
if( preg_match('/[\x00-\xFF][\x00-\xFF][\x00-\xFF]/', 'text') ) {
 //do stuff
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/RO6Xgr)

When using single quotes, the `\x` notation is treated as if it was `\\x` and is handled by the regex engine properly.

Comment: Wow, a difference between single and double quote is also learned, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[^\x00-\x7F]

I found something like this that takes x00.
I actually used it for special character detection.